# Как выбрать дочерние элементы первого уровня

Tags: html, css

Как изменить стили только у li с надписью `Категория 1 ур.`

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class='kategoria1'>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>
        Категория 2 ур.
        <ul>
          <li>Категория 3 ур.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='kategoria1'>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='kategoria1'>Категория 1 ур.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `.main-menu > li { ... }` вот так просто...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать так, как написал в комментариях [**@OPTIMUS PRIME**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007470/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F#comment1708064_1007470), т.е. использовать дочерние элементы `ul > li` и выдать им стиль..
Но это не всё, т.е. у вас в `ul li` вложены ещё элементы, то придётся их "ограничить" от изменений.

Допустим вам нужно поменять только цвет у `li` первого уровня:

```css
/* Изменяем цвет у первого уровня */
.main-menu > li {color: red;}
/* "Возвращаем" оригинальный цвет у остальных, что выше первого уровня */
.main-menu > li * {color: black;}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>
        Категория 2 ур.
        <ul>
          <li>Категория 3 ур.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Категория 1 ур.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.kategoria1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class='kategoria1'>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>
        Категория 2 ур.
        <ul>
          <li>Категория 3 ур.</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='kategoria1'>
    Категория 1 ур.
    <ul>
      <li>Категория 2 ур.</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='kategoria1'>Категория 1 ур.</li>
</ul>
```

Все. Просто даешь класс всем элементам которые нужно изменить (если что, не обязательно давать класс `kategoria1` делай какой хочешь). Попробуй скопировать весь мой код и посмотри что получится.

Comment: А теперь сами посмотрите, что получилось в результате..